# How can I have a messagebox which can be dragged out? like toast notifications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to show a custom message on top of the screen and user can drag it to the right to close it. Like toast notifications, or twitter internal messages.

I couldn't find any codes for this and haven't any idea how to implement it. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `ToastPrompt` from the `Coding4Fun` library:

[image]

More info on the [official documentation page](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toast%20Prompt).